# Javascript execution error in Sublime

Tags: javascript, undefined, sublimetext3

I am learning JavaScript and this is my 1st week :)

```js
var Module = (function () {
    // code
    var publicMethod = {};

    var privateMethod = function(someStringToBePassed) {
        debug("I love USA. "+someStringToBePassed);
    }

    publicMethod.someFunction = function() {
        privateMethod("USA is sexy");
    }
    return publicMethod;
})();

debug(Module.someFunction());
```

I am executing this in Sublime. I am seeing the following result.

```
--> I love USA. USA is sexy
--> undefined
```

Please explain why I am seeing undefined here.

```
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Please tell me why I am seeing "undefined" in the results

Comment: It's because you're calling `someFunction` and then immediately passing the result to `debug`. Either remove the second debug, or replace the first debug with a `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from someFunction. Try this:

Now someFunction returns the value of privateMethod. privateMethod returns the constructed string.

```js
var Module = (function () {
// code
var publicMethod = {};

var privateMethod = function(someStringToBePassed) {
return "I love USA. "+someStringToBePassed;
}

publicMethod.someFunction = function() {
return privateMethod("USA is sexy");
}
return publicMethod;
})();

debug(Module.someFunction());
```

Comment: Hey Thomas,
Thanks for the reply. If I replace Module.someFunction() with Module.publicMethod() or Module.publicMethod, it gives me an error. Is there any reason why I can't refer publicMethod outside

Comment: When your code executes, the `Module` object gets reference to `publicMethod` object, since you are returning it from the self-invocated function. 
So, `Module` have access to the properties of `publicMethod` object only (for your example it's only `someFunction`). 
You can find more info just searching for "javascript module pattern". some example is here - https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var Module = (function () {
//code
   var publicMethod = {};

   var privateMethod = function(someStringToBePassed) {
        return ("I love USA. "+someStringToBePassed);
    }

    publicMethod.someFunction = function() {
      return  privateMethod("USA is sexy");
    }
    return publicMethod;
})();

var sample = Module;
console.log(sample.someFunction())
```